# I cannot edit my JTextArea when I create a Socket Object in the same method?

Tags: java, swing, serversocket

```
  try
    {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(Port);
        txaLogs.setText("It works");
        //Socket socket = serverSocket.accept(); 
        System.out.println("Socket opened");

    } catch (Exception e)
    {
    }

    //CODE 2

    try
    {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(Port);
        txaLogs.setText("It works");
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();                    //ADDED LINE
        System.out.println("Socket opened");

    } catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/o31gF.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BATI1.jpg

When I add the line of code "Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();" , it does not write anything to the text area. Its the weirdest thing ive seen. Cause the code to write to the text area comes BEFORE the line of added code. So im not sure why it doesnt get written to the text area. (Im doing this in Netbeans within the code of the button Jbutton2)

Comment: The added line blocks the Swing EDT, so no updates to the UI will be drawn until someone connects to the socket. Updating the text area only schedules a redraw operation - the actual redraw takes places after your method ends.

Comment: *Im doing this in Netbeans within the code of the button Jbutton2)*  - A Socket blocks. Since your code is invoked from the listener it is executed on the Event Dispatch Thread which will now prevent the GUI from responding to events. Your `Socket` needs to be created on a separate `Thread`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information. You can use the `SwingWorker` as described in the tutorial. You can also search the forum for other example that use a "Socket".

Comment: 1) `catch (Exception e) { }` Don't ignore exceptions! Unless logging is implemented, at least call `Throwable.printStackTrace()` 2) Only tag an IDE once code has been tested in *another* IDE and been seen to work (indicating a problem with the first IDE).

Comment: @camickr Thanks, thats a big help. Its just a problem because if I open a socket on a new thread, im not sure how I can update the GUI from that other thread. Say i have a while loop waiting for clients to connect and I want to update the GUI each time a client connects... how would I implement that?

Comment: *im not sure how I can update the GUI from that other thread.* Read the tutorial link I provided! The `SwingWorker` allows you to do this easily by "publishing" values as they are received.